# how add facebook "download conversion action" for flutter app?

Tags: flutter, facebook, facebook-events

I am starting an advertising company on Facebook. I will receive an "need add a download conversion action" warning. can I add this event with plugin [facebook_app_events](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events)? example:

```
facebookAppEvents.logEvent(
    name: 'download',
    parameters: {
      'custom_parameter': 'value',
    },
  );
```

Is this what Facebook expects from my app?
or do i need something else? I also use Firebase Analystycs in my app.

Answer (score 0):

To track the mobile app events for advertising purposes on Facebook, you should use Facebook SDK to log app events, including the conversions you want to track, such as a download conversion action. The code you provided is close, but you need to ensure you are setting the correct event name and parameters according to Facebook's SDK guidelines.

You can proceed with the following steps:

Integrate the Facebook SDK to your app if you haven't done so. You can follow the instructions for your specific platform (iOS, Android, or React Native) from Facebook for Developers: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events

Now, it's essential to choose the correct event name while logging the event. For standard events, you can use the predefined event names available in the Facebook SDK. For a download conversion action, you can use 'fb_mobile_purchase,' 'fb_mobile_complete_registration,' or create a custom event name depending on how you define a download conversion action for your situation.

Example for logging a standard event with custom parameters (replace 'YourEventName' with the appropriate event name):

```
facebookAppEvents.logEvent(
    name: 'YourEventName',
    parameters: {
      'custom_parameter': 'value',
    },
  );
```

If you also use Firebase Analytics, remember to separately log events with Firebase's event tracking methods. Facebook SDK events and Firebase Analytics events are separate and need to be implemented individually in your app.
Once you have implemented the event tracking correctly, the warning should no longer appear, and you should start seeing the reported app events in your Facebook Ads Manager.

Keep in mind that you will also need to create a custom conversion action on Facebook Ads Manager based on the event you have just logged, which you can use as a tracking objective for your advertising campaigns. Instructions for creating custom conversions are available here: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/780705975381000

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy